# Advanced Data Aggregation with MongoDB and Python

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a task involving the aggregation and processing of data stored in a **MongoDB** collection named `flight_data`. This collection holds a wealth of information about *flights, encompassing details such as flight numbers, departure airports, arrival airports, fuel consumption, and flight distances*.

Here's a glimpse of the document structure within the `flight_data` collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("3f94fb7faff0b71ae5e3cb8d"),
    "flight_number": "SWA4146",
    "departure_airport": "SNA",
    "arrival_airport": "SMF",
    "fuel_consumption_gallons": 700.4,
    "flight_distance_miles": 450
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the total fuel consumption for each unique flight route, and I aim to identify the routes that have consumed the most fuel. My desired output format is:

```
{
    "route": "SNA-SMF",
    "total_fuel_consumption_gallons": THE_CALCULATED_AMOUNT
},
{
    "route": "SFO-ORD",
    "total_fuel_consumption_gallons": THE_CALCULATED_AMOUNT
}
```

Here's my **Python** script:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client["aviation_data"]
collection = db["flight_data"]

pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "departure_airport": "$departure_airport",
                "arrival_airport": "$arrival_airport"
            },
            "total_fuel_consumption_gallons": {
                "$sum": "$fuel_consumption_gallons"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "route": {
                "$concat": ["$_id.departure_airport", "-", "$_id.arrival_airport"]
            },
            "total_fuel_consumption_gallons": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "total_fuel_consumption_gallons": -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$limit": 5
    }
]

result = list(collection.aggregate(pipeline))
print(result)
```

However, when I execute the script, I encounter this error:

`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The field 'departure_airport' must be an accumulator object`

Does anyone know where the error is here? I've seen some similar questions, but I couldn't fix my script using the answers that I found.

Comment: I suspect that the error could be related to `"$project"`, but with what exactly?

Comment: First of all if you have additional information/suspicions to add to your question then please edit it to do so rather than adding it as a comment. Secondly, and I don't mean to be 'that person', but are you sure that's the error you're getting for the code you posted? Seems to work fine in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SCwb4Pj4LnM). Generally an error like that would be if the `$group` was inappropriately defined, such as with [this other playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/otNrpTK_cIa)

Comment: Is this your real code? It should work fine without any errors.

Answer (score 2):

I can't figure out why [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77284516/20042973) (LLM generated?) was upvoted and accepted. It is not correct.

In [a comment I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284498/advanced-data-aggregation-with-mongodb-and-python/77284624#comment136247922_77284498), I asked if the aggregation as written in the question was yielding the error message shared. [This playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SxDGrAvKYz3), which uses the sample document and the aggregation (directly copied from the question) completes successfully.

Typically error messages stating that the system is expecting an `accumulator object` are related to the `$group` stage (*not* the `$project` stage as the other answer claims). This is because [accumulator operators are used in the `$group` stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator). From [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#syntax) the syntax of `$group` is:

```
{
 $group:
   {
     _id: <expression>, // Group key
     <field1>: { <accumulator1> : <expression1> },
     ...
   }
 }
```

And indeed that is exactly what is provided in the description of this question. However if we improperly move the `departure_airport` field outside of the `_id` definition in the `$group` stage as follows:

```
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "arrival_airport": "$arrival_airport"
      },
      "departure_airport": "$departure_airport",
      "total_fuel_consumption_gallons": {
        "$sum": "$fuel_consumption_gallons"
      }
    }
```

Then we get the exact error message provided in the question:

```
query failed: (Location40234) The field 'departure_airport' must be an accumulator object
```

The playground demonstration of this can be found [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JCx0jROsMY0).

The `$project` stage defined in the question is syntactically valid and just fine. Moreover, the other answer "solves" the supposed problem with generating the `route` field in the `$project` stage by adding a preceding `$addFields` stage to handle it. That answer claims that this "*eliminat[es] the error and ensur[es] that you can achieve the intended results*."But the problem with the logic in that claim is that it relies on those two stages being 'different' in some meaningful way. However per [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/):

> The `$addFields` stage is equivalent to a $project stage that explicitly specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields.

So to summarize:

1. I don't see evidence that the aggregation stage provided in the question generates the error in the question. (If it does, please share a link to a mongoplayground so that we can investigate further).
2. The currently accepted answer neither does anything to solve the problem nor is the logic it is based on correct.